# Reference parent object (is there a better way?)

Tags: php

Is there a better way to do this in php? I've tried extending but it doesn't seem to be what I want. Basically I want the end result to be the same as it is now, but it just seems like a lot to pass a reference then have to reference it through the $this object;

You can ignore any basic mistakes, typed this quick.

```
$main = new Main;
$main->sub->SetMessage();
echo $main->displayMessage;
```

I want to be able to access the display message under the main class but have it edited by the subclass

Here is my code,

```
class Main
{
    public $displayMessage;
    public $sub;

    function __construct() 
    {
        $this->sub= new SubClass(&$this);
    }
}

class SubClass
{
        public $caller;

        function __construct(&$callingObj) 
        {
            $this->caller = $callingObj;
        }

        function SetMessage()
        {
            $this->caller->displayMessage = "This is the Display Message";
        }
}
```

Any advice is much appreciated. I did search before posting, extensively. Maybe I just don't know how to properly word the question.

Comment: It works if you add `$` to both `public $displayMessage;` and `public $sub;` and remove the `&` from `$this->sub= new SubClass($this);`. Also missing a close `}` on the `Main` construct...

Comment: Thanks, the code I have works, those were just typing mistakes, Just looking for a shorter way to get the same end result.

Comment: So you just want to reference the `displayMessage` from the subclass is all, just not in so many lines?

Comment: Basically yeah. Just seems like there is a better way out there maybe I'm not seeing? I don't want to extend because I want to be able to access the display message under the main class but have it edited by the subclass. If that makes sense.